# Get Maximum Length allowed in column | Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, maxlength

How to get the Max and Min length allowed in column of `varchar2`.
I have to test for incoming data from the temp table which is coming from some remote db. And each row value is to be tested for specific columns that it has maximum or minimum value which can be set into the column.

So I was to get the column specs using its schema details. I did make a `proc` for that:

```
PROCEDURE CHK_COL_LEN(VAL IN VARCHAR2,             
                       MAX_LEN IN NUMBER :=4000,
                       MIN_LEN IN NUMBER :=0,
                       LEN_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
        IS
            BEGIN
               IF LENGTH(VAL)<MIN_LEN THEN
                    LEN_OUT := 'ERROR';
                    RETURN;
               ELSIF LENGTH(VAL)>MAX_LEN THEN
                    LEN_OUT := 'ERROR';
                    RETURN;
               ELSE
                    LEN_OUT := 'SUCCESS';
                    RETURN;
               END IF;
            END;
END CHK_COL_LEN;
```

But the problem is, it is not reusable and is a bit hardcoded. I have to explicitly send `MAX` and `MIN` value for each value along with the data to be checked.

So at the `proc` call, it's something like:

```
CHK_COL_LEN(EMP_CURSOR.EMP_ID, 5, 1, LEN_ERROR_MSG);
```

I instead want something like: (If something like this exist!)

```
CHK_COL_LEN(EMP_CURSOR.EMP_ID, 
               EMP.COLUMN_NAME%MAX_LENGTH, 
               EMP.COLUMN_NAME%MIN_LENGTH, 
               LEN_ERROR_MSG)
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
select max(length(col)) from table;
```

This is a solution, but again I will have to run this query each time to set the two variables for MAX and MIN value. And running  extra two queries for each value and then setting 2 variables will cost be significant lose in performance when in have about 32 tables, each with 5-8 varchar2 columns and average rows of about 40k-50k in each table

Comment: But max(length(col)) will give you max existing length, that's not necessarily the MAX_LENGTH of your column. I think @road242 is right, the only way of get a column size is using dictionary.

Comment: Why are you trying to write a validation using the data dictionary instead of letting the table's definition do the validation for you?

Comment: Because, i want to catch that before hand. As once the exception is thrown(even if it is handled manually) it then skips the operations to be scheduled later(take a scenario when only few loop counts occurred and then the exceptions thrown), then loop ends at first exception occurrence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the table 'user_tab_columns table' to retrieve metadata information of a specific table:

```
SELECT 
   COLUMN_NAME, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_PRECISION 
FROM 
   user_tab_columns 
WHERE 
   t.table_name IN ('<YOURTABLE>');
```

with this information you can query the metadata directly in your stored procedure:

```
...
SELECT 
   CHAR_LENGTH INTO max_length 
FROM 
   user_tab_columns 
WHERE 
   table_name = '<YOURTABLE>' AND COLUMN_NAME = '<YOURCOLUMN>';

...
```

Exmple Procedure to get **max length of table/column:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GET_MAX_LENGTH_OF_COLUMN(    
                       tableName IN VARCHAR2,
                       columnName IN VARCHAR2,
                       MAX_LENGTH OUT VARCHAR2)
        IS
            BEGIN

            SELECT CHAR_LENGTH INTO MAX_LENGTH 
            FROM user_tab_columns 
            WHERE table_name = tableName AND COLUMN_NAME = columnName;            

END GET_MAX_LENGTH_OF_COLUMN;
```

Comment: Yeah, with this i can get the length of course. But it's not of that much use, as for every column, i will have to write such big code and get the value to set into a variable and then pass the variable in proc. Also i can't write the TABLE NAME in proc, coz proc is reuable and used my about 32 tables. So made a common proc for all tables.

Comment: why? you can use table name + column name as input parameter, so you would have to write this procedure only once.

Comment: You are right, but unfortunately, in Oracle, table name can't be dynamic. Not a single schema name can be dynamic in Oracle, and have to be hardcoded. The limitation of oracle.

Comment: working for me. See edited answer, with procedure to show max-length of a column (works as pasted)

Comment: no table name or schema name is dynamic here, the statement just retrieves metadata using existing oracle-system-tables

Comment: But actually when I pass the table name as parameter, then the query is to be executed using THAT parameter in place of table name. And that Oracle doesn't allow.

Comment: I think @road242 is referring to the dynamic location of max length (please note, you might need to take into account BYTE / CHAR lengths depending on character set) whereas @Sachin is now talking about dynamically querying the data from a varying table to compare to the max length... for that you will need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to allow you to do dynamic querying inside the procedure.

Comment: Like @Captain said: I am talking about the solution mentioned by me. The procedure GET_MAX_LENGTH_OF_COLUMN has no variable table/column names in it... It compiles & works like written above (trust me or if not then compile and run it).

Comment: Done .. @Captain is right, I misinterpreted it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your procedure like this:

```
create or replace procedure Checking_size(column_name varchar2,columnvalue varchar2,state out varchar2) is

begin
execute immediate 'declare
z '||column_name||'%type;
begin
z:=:param2;
end;' using columnvalue;

state:='OK';
exception when value_error then
state:='NOT OK';

end;
```

As you can see i simulate an error assignment. If `columnvalue` length is bigger than the column i pass as `column_name` it will throws value_error exception and return `NOT OK`, else return `OK`.
For example, if `your_table.your_column` refer to a column with length (3) then return `NOT OK`.

```
declare 
state varchar2(10);
begin

Checking_size('your_table.your_column','12345',state);
dbms_output.put_line(state);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of tables is not much you can specify the MIN Value using [CHECK Constraint](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52180) on the table.

Any DML on the table would automatically fail if it exceeds length assigned to that column.

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
(
 supplier_id numeric(4),
 supplier_name varchar2(50),
 CONSTRAINT check_supplier_id
 CHECK (length(supplier_name) > 5 )
 );
```

Comment: Yes, but the check is to be done before DML. That's why initially the data is stored in a Temp table and then after checking the DML is to be executed. The result should be get caught beforehand any exception! Because for client the exception should be triggered on very serious issues and not this kind.

Comment: how is the EMP_CURSOR.EMP_ID cursor build